Getting banking security codes without a U.S. phone number
I live in Japan, but still have an account at Bank of America in the US. Often, the bank wants to send me security codes via SMS, and they’ll only send the SMS message to a US phone number, which I no longer have. Any suggestions about how to solve this problem? I suppose I could just buy a U.S. phone contract, but it seems ridiculous to pay $$$ just to receive a few text messages.
Edit
After a bit of research, I found that there are service like TextNow and Hushed that provide “virtual” US numbers. These can generally receive text messages, but bank security codes are often sent from “short code” numbers, which they don’t support. So, still stuck.
Good info here. But that answer is 4 years old, and cellular tech changes pretty fast.
Another edit:
This and this look pretty promising. Anyone used it, or something similar? $7/month is still a lot to pay for a few text messages, but I can live with that.

Cross post: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/163282/which-banks-send-security-codes-by-non-sms-methods

This question is similar to: Navigating Capital One's two factor SMS authentication from outside the United States. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Would something like NumberBarn work? With a PAYG SIM to avoid contract costs?

The NumberBarn web site says:
*NumberBarn's numbers are classified as "wireline" or landline. Some short code verification messages will only be sent to wireless phone numbers as it is the policy of the sender. *  Doesn't sound very promising.
